# Detect file size decrease

Tags: scripts, filesystem, files

I am saving streams from browser cache into my home folder. I wrote a script that takes the specific data type and saves them into disk, and names them as `data.1`, `data.2 , data.3` and so on, creating new file names without overwriting the old ones.

Sometimes the stream gets reset and starts from the beginning. When this happens the size of the new file `data.n` decreases compared to `data.n-1`. Would it be possible to detect this decrease in file size and alert me (Say with a terminal beep)?